# Parse a string with timezone offset into DateTime doesn't require conversion to UniversalTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have data in my SQL server database that is filtered based on date. I store the data in UTC time always. I have an API that accepts a From and To date filter to fetch these records.

I was facing issue with the filter since the frontend was in a different timezone and they were sending the date in their local time. I have asked them send the datetime in the following format,

> "2024-01-22 23:59:59 +0200"

+0200 is the additional information that I required from them which the timezone offset for whichever timezone the frontend was in.

They send this date in the query string and my API parsed this date into

> "22/01/2024 21:59:59"

My question is does .NET itself take care of applying the provided offset and calculate the UTC time?

```
filter.StartDateTime.Value.ToUniversalTime()
```

Is this conversion no longer required and pointless?

Comment: Is `filter.StartDateTime` a `DateTime?` ? Or `DateTimeOffset?` ? Or something completely different?

Comment: Don't use `DateTime` if you care about offsets to begin with. If `StartDateTime` is a DateTimeOffset you won't have to call `ToUniversalTime()` at all. `my API parsed this date into` that's very suspicious due to the format, not the value. The standard way of representing dates in JSON is ISO8601, ie the original format. Why did a localized date string appear in the API response?

Comment: Finally, `I store the data in UTC time always.` that doesn't prevent offset problems. Changes to DST rules aren't as rare as you assume. Russia changed DST rules at least thee times within 5 years. Egypt changed the rules twice with just a few weeks notice. The UTC values you calculate today may no longer represent the correct local time should the rules change. Read Jon Skeet's [Storing UTC is not a Silver Bullet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The client/frontend has calendar controls and they send the datetime in their localtime.

Comment: And you can't just force them to use UTC for sending? I mean you seem to force them to send the offset. So seems easy to just enforce UTC instead. DateTime only distinct local and UTC getting Timezone Handling right takes more then calling a method on the DateTime class.

Comment: The use case that I use is not as complex or as time sensitive. I understand there are complexities with datetimes. I work with a legacy application where the database cannot change at all.

Comment: That means your database is a lot more susceptible to offset changes than you realize. The standard way of dealing with such issues is to store the *local* time along with the IANA timezone name, eg `Europe/Amsterdam` and use the IANA timezone database to calculate the correct local time. This is standard almost everywhere except Windows. Flights for example are published as local airport time along with the IANA tz name. .NET itself doesn't use IANA timezones but [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) does and even comes with tzdb bundled

Comment: @user1890098 post your code. We can't guess what's going on just by the date strings. `DateTime` is rather ambiguous with a `Kind` property that can be Local, UTC or Unknown. Dates loaded from a database are always Unknown. Dates loaded from a database are always Unknown but generally treated as local. You may only have to specify that the `DateTime` values you retrieved are `UTC`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's pretty much my code. All I do is use the filter.StartDateTime property and set it inside a where clause in a LINQ.

Comment: The code that produces `filter.StartDateTime` from `2024-01-22 23:59:59 +0200` is missing. If you use `DateTime.Parse` you always get a *local* time, with the time adjusted   from the specified to the local machine's timezone. You can control this through the `styles` parameter. If you use `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` you'll get Kind=Utc and a value adjusted from the offset to UTC no matter the local offset

Comment: BTW a better way to filter is to use `< endDate.Date.AddDays(1)`. A lot of things can happen in 1s and the lack of precision in SQL Server's `datetime` type means you can end up with fractional values when you least expect it

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the date settings of the machine the code is executed on.

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("2024-01-22 23:59:59 +0200");
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

If I execute this code on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wFb405) the output will be

> 1/22/2024 9:59:59 PM

The server is probably set to use UTC timezone, that's why it shows an *already converted* DateTime

If I execute it on my local machine (in France, actually UTC +1), I get this output :

> 22/01/2024 22:59:59

It's all about regional settings (also note the date format of the output on my machine, which is the FR-fr one)

In your case, the API is executed on a machine with UTC timezone. It's not offset, it's using its local timezone